# Get height of the div and adjust others based on height detected

Tags: jquery

Need help to get height of the li div element adjust the height of other li div based on the highest height detected.

It works fine on onload. When i refresh the page, script not working again. Please guide me.

**JS:**

```
var maxHeight = -1;

$('.product-item .content').each(function() {
  maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
});

$('.product-item .content').each(function() {
  $(this).height(maxHeight);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="related-products">

    <li>
        <div class="product-item">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="/image1.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">Hello</div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="product-item">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="/image2.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">Hello1<br>Hello2<br>Hello</div>
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: i cant see class= content anywhere

Comment: try CSS table layout display:table for ul , table-row for li and table-cell for div that should take care these issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have re written you HTML code, because you have useless `div` :

```
<ul id="related-products">
  <li class="product-item min-height407">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="/content/protect-badge.png" alt="">
      </div>
    <div class="content">Hello</div>
  </li>
  <li class="product-item min-height407">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="/content/protect-badge.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="content">Hello1<br>Hello2<br>Hello</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then in JS, you set a variable `maxHeight` to `0`, and loop on `ul li`, to find the utmost value of li. Then, you happen to all of your `li` the value. You may apply it at the document ready.

```
var maxHeight = 0;
$('#related-products li').each(function (i,e) {
    if ($(e).height() > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = $(e).height();
    }
});
// And then apply this max height to all li into ul#related-products
$('#related-products li').css({'height' : maxHeight});
```

Please find this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zlen/bL1o9rjb/1/). I have add style for your comprehension

Comment: The second each can also be `$('#related-products li').css({'height' : maxHeight});`

Comment: Perfect @WenceslaoNegrete ! I had not thought of that simple. I have updated my post

Comment: Hi @Zl3n... Thanks for your script. getting <li> contents dynamically from backend.. whenever i refresh the page, different contents & images will load inside <li>. On refreshing, script not get loaded. from 2nd time, style: height is missing from html tag.. please let me know your comments

Comment: @TDG : the jsfiddle works even if you load and reload the page. I think you have a problem in you script.

Comment: @Zl3n - Your code works.. It my make.. i put your code outside the ajax  call.. thats it not loads from 2nd refresh. It works. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @TDG. If you vote me up in addition to solve, you will get a bonus +2 :) I'm not sure you know this tips